# Number of ways of both full house and 4 of a kind

Tags: combinatorics

If 2 players are dealt a hand in poker, I am wondering what the number of ways that both players get a full house is.

My guess is that if we suppose player A gets a full house

${13}\choose{1}$${4}\choose{3}$${12}\choose{1}$${4}\choose{2}$ ways

Then player B can get their full house in

${11}\choose{1}$${4}\choose{3}$(1+${10}\choose{1}$${4}\choose{2}$) ways

with the extra $+1$ because one of player B's pairs can also be taken from the denomination that player A's pair was in (e.g. if player A had 2 aces, player B could still have had 2 aces).

Multiplying these $2$ numbers we get $10,048,896$. Is this correct? I'm not sure if my reasoning is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $